Django: форма с неизвестным количеством подформ
Прошу совета, может быть кто-то уже встречался с подобной задачей.
Пишу систему регистрации доступов пользователей (красный на рисунке) к серверам (синий на рисунке) через заявку (оранжевый на рисунке). Не понимаю как в Django описать форму чтобы ее можно было обработать средствами Django, а не в ручную создавая по очереди: сначала сохранить всех переданных пользователей(таблица users), записав созданные id, потом сохранить все сервера (таблица servers), записав созданные id, потом сохранить основную заявку (таблица tickets) и затем во вложенных циклах создавать записи в таблице доступов(access).

Подробнее:
Система призвана вести учет выданных доступов к серверам конкретным пользователям через систему заявок. Т.е. некий ответственный человек создает заявку, в которой указывает, что конкретным пользователям (красные поля формы - условно тип1, количество заранее не известно, дополнительные формы добавляются на фронте через JS) нужно предоставить доступ к конкретным серверам (синие поля формы - условно тип2, поведение такое же как у тип1). Надо это сохранить в бд.
В БД реализована следующая модель отношений:

Как реализовать такую форму (речь про forms.py) чтобы джанго смог ее сформировать из request.POST, типа ticket = TicketForm(request.POST), а не в ручную создавать кучу форм, и потом корректно сохранить в БД с созданием нужных связей.
Не прошу рабочий код, укажите пожалуйста направление в котором стоит копать чтобы реализовать задуманное или скажите что-то типа "все делают такое вручную - терпи":)

Если такую форму можно будет еще как-то адекватно передать в рендер и отобразить в шаблоне (jinja2) с кнопками типа добавить/удалить подформу (т.е. уйти от самописного JS) будет вообще замечательно.
